# change Uislider value on tapping at particular point

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I want to fire an action upon tapping at a particular point on UISlider by tapping, not by dragging the slider thumb.

How can I tap on a UISlider at a point to set the slider value?

A snippet of code would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something on your own?

Comment: i have tried it by putting custom buttons but its not the correct way. also i tried defining touchdown and touch up inside events for slider but none of them works.

Answer (score 36):

```
    UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] init] autorelease];
…
```

slider setup

```
…
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sliderTapped:)] autorelease];
[slider addGestureRecognizer:gr];
- (void)sliderTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g {
     UISlider* s = (UISlider*)g.view;
    if (s.highlighted)
        return; // tap on thumb, let slider deal with it
    CGPoint pt = [g locationInView: s];
    CGFloat percentage = pt.x / s.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat delta = percentage * (s.maximumValue - s.minimumValue);
    CGFloat value = s.minimumValue + delta;
    [s setValue:value animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to fire an event for UIControlEventValueChanged :-)

Comment: As @DanVanWinkle stated don't forget to fire control event, otherwise your UI will update but your backend won't. To fire event call this at end of sliderTapped:         [s sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with UIControl's addTarget:action:forControlEvents: API?

Answer (score 2):

Try uiview touchesbegan function if v1 is a uiview with plain background behind that place uislider\

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch view] == v1)
  {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:v1];
    NSInteger i = location.x;
  }
```

then get the percentage of xpoint by multiplying with v1 frame that is if v1 frame x value =50 and i = 5means 10 percent then multiply the percentage value with slider value to change the slider value

Comment: @user1389841 If u think the answer is useful dont forget that u can accept the answer.

Comment: You can also go with touches moved function for sliding after tap the view.